# Android Dagger 2.10 ou maior - void inject X @BindsInstance?

Tags: android, injeção-de-dependência

Estou com uma grande duvida sobre o correto uso do dagger 2.10 ou superior para android implementando segundo as especificações da documentação do Dagger para Android.

**Codigo de exemplo:**

```
@Singleton
        @Component(modules = {
                AndroidInjectionModule.class,
                ApplicationModulo.class,
                ViewBuilderModule.class
                })
        public interface FipeApplicationComponent extends AndroidInjector<FipeApplication>{


            @Component.Builder
            interface Builder{
                @BindsInstance
                FipeApplicationComponent.Builder application(FipeApplication application);

                @BindsInstance
                FipeApplicationComponent.Builder urlBase(String urlBase);

                FipeApplicationComponent build();
            }

            void inject(FipeApplication app);

        }
```

1. BindsInstance

Antigamente quando queriamos vincular alguma instancia de algum classe que precisasse ser instanciada fora dos domínios do dagger passavamos essa instancia pelo construtor.
Agora é sugerido usar **@BindsInstance** dentro de um **@Component.Builder
        interface Builder**

2. void inject

Vejo em alguns exemplos na internet o uso do void inject(FipeApplication app) sendo que conforme o item anterior que eu perguntei aqui ja tem um:

```
...    
@Component.Builder
                interface Builder{
                    @BindsInstance
                    FipeApplicationComponent.Builder application(FipeApplication application);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A minha duvida era quando usar o BindsInstance vs Inject no Component.

Na verdade são duas coisas diferentes:

O **BindsInstance** serve para vincular alguma instancia dentro dos domínios do Dagger que não esteja na árvore, algo que precise vir de fora ja instanciado. Um Context por exemplo.

O **void inject(MyClassXXX myObjectXXX)** serve para indicar aonde o Dagger será "autorizado" injetar as dependências.

void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

void inject(SecondActivity secondActivity);

void inject(Presenter presenter);

Assim dentro do MainActivity, SecondActivity ou Presenter podemos fazer:

....
@Inject
protected Context mContext;
...